# does Javascript have many trojans and viruses like Java applets? How to best protect against them?

Tags: javascript

I thought Javascript does not have viruses like Java applets do. I turned off my Java plugin in the browser, but I can't really turn off Javascript. Nothing would work if I did.

This is an example:

I was just browsing for Javascript tutorials and on GWT and one of the blog sites had Javascript virus.

Any one knows anything about this? Here is screen shot of what my ESET reported on my PC. It seems to have blocked it.

[image]

It is called JS/IFramne.DE trojan, and was coming from a bad site called *www.gmarwaha.com/blog*

(**DO NOT CLICK OR GO TO THE ABOVE SITE, IT HAS JAVASCRIPT TROJAN, BAD SITE!**)

My question is, how to protect myself from Javascript viruses and trojans?

Is Javascript just as bad as java applets when it comes to viruses? Other than having anti virus installed on the PC, and be smart above which web sites to visit, what else can one do?

I am starting to think that one should not even be on the internet at all any more.

Everywhere one goes, there is a virus and trojan, and now Javascript also.

Comment: javascript isn't nearly as bad as java for infecting a system. java can directly execute new processes on your machine. JS requires holes in your browser to do so, and those holes tend to be browser specificic. Java's holes apply to the system as a whole and can usually be exploited from ANY browser.

Comment: This would be better suited on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: I am the author of the website you have mentioned. The behavior you were seeing was because my hosting server got hacked and malicious scripts were injected into my wordpress blog. It it completely clean  now and has been that way for quite sometime now. I just noticed this thread and wanted to clarify any misconceptions that still remain. BTW, that is not a bad site. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case where 3rd party widgets go rogue or the whole site.

JS itself isn't a virus building language nor does it have access to the system. It's isolated in the browser. However, JS can be used to redirect you to a malicious site or embed an iframe that displays the malicious site. But JS isn't the language that carries out the attack, it just aids the attack.

The main attack is carried out when the browser itself or it's plugins have security flaws or features that attackers exploit. The most recent attacks were on Java and Flash, where both plugins have access to the local machine resources.